# Find $x$ and $y$ value in simple equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$x - 7350 y = 1070$$
$$x - 15080y = 430$$
$$x = ?$$    $$y = ?$$

Hi

I'm trying to find the value of $x$ and $y$ but proving hard any help would be greatly appreciated!

What would be the approach here?

Comment: Substract the second equation form the first to get rid of $x$, then you have $y$ and then in turn $x$. Alternatively use the second equation to express $x$ in terms of $y$ and plug that into the other equation.

Comment: could you show me with the above example please?

Answer (score 6):

Substract one of the equations form the other to get rid of $x$, then you have $y$ and then in turn $x$:

$x - 7350\ y = 1070$

$x - 15080\ y = 430$

So

$(x - 7350\ y) - (x - 15080\ y)= 1070-430,$

and this is  just an implicit expression for $y$ as $x$ cancels out:

$(-7350 + 15080)\ y= (1070-430)\ \ \Longrightarrow\ \ y= \frac{640}{7730}= \frac{64}{773}.$

Once you got that, the value of $x$ follows by plugging in the obtained $y$ value to one of the equations:

$x - 7350\ y = 1070\ \ \Longrightarrow\ \ x = 1070+7350\ \left(\frac{64}{773}\right)=\frac{1297510}{773}.$

---

Alternatively use one equation to express $x$ in terms of $y$ and plug that into the other equation:

$x - 15080\ y = 430\ \ \Longrightarrow\ \ x = 430+15080\ y,$

$x - 7350\ y = 1070\ \ \Longrightarrow\ \ (430+15080\ y) - 7350\ y = 1070,$

which is just the same equation as above.

---

Also, see

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation,

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations,

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_elimination,

and here the computational solution:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve[{x+-+7350+y+%3D%3D+1070%2C+x+-+15080+y+%3D%3D+430}%2C{x%2Cy}]

Comment: wow thats amazing thanks very much!

Comment: According to your computation there's a typo in "use the second equation to express". It should be "use the first equation to express".

Comment: @AméricoTavares: I couldn't find it (the second equation is the one with 15080 right?) Anyway, I edited the words "first" and "second" out of the answer as they don't really matter.

Comment: @gilesadamthomas: I updated it for more detail and also added a second link on "Gauss elimination", which gives the general principle behind the solving algorithm. Also, the "accept answer button" is right below the upvote number on the left.

Answer (score 0):

Subtracting equation-1 from equation-2, we get

$(x-15080y) - (x-7350y) = 430 - 1070=-640$

$-7730y = -640$

$7730y = 640$

$y = 640/7730=64/773$

Putting the value of $y$ in equation-1, we get

$x - 7350(64/773) = 1070$

$x - 470400/773 = 1070$

$x = 1070 + 470400/773$

$x = 827110+470400/773=1297510/773$

Therefore, $x = 1297510/773,  y = 64/773$.